# break does not stop while

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am using the while and performing a check inside it, I put a breakpoint in the else and it looks like everything is ok, the code performs the verification and goes to the BREAK, however the loop does not stop ...

```
Cliente cliente = null;

do {
  cliente = DataBase.Clientes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == 0);

  if (cliente.NossoNumero == string.Empty || cliente.Email == string.Empty) {
    cliente.UpdateStatus(Status.Error);
  } 
  else {
    break;
  }
}
while (DataBase.Clientes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == 0) != null);

return cliente;
```

Comment: why you need a loop for a single element BTW?

Comment: The `while` is an infinite loop if the result is not `null`

Comment: Can you please use `LiceCap` to take an animated gif 'video' of the `break` being hit and **not** exiting the loop? _It definitely **should** work._

Comment: If you want to just exit the function completely put in a return; instead of a break;.

Comment: Are you sure, you debuging the least version of your code? Sometimes, visual studio run in debug mode but, dll's belong to earlier version of code. Then you cannot debug the code you see.

Comment: thanks guys, but i just fixed it https://pastebin.com/mfJ0XNja, I do not know what was wrong with the code I posted earlier :(

Comment: Can you share UpdateStatus method and Status enum?

Comment: You claim that the `break;` statement will not terminate the `do` loop even when it is the innermost statement to which `break;` could correspond. That is hardly credible. You should produce a complete program with which we can reproduce the problem. Other comments and answers give useful suggestions based on what they think your code should have been. But nobody can answer why a `break;` does not break, because nobody else has ever seen that happen. Do you do anything unusual when you debug?

Answer (score -1):

if you have more than one clinet?
why won't you return a list of IEnumrable and then update each client?

also the loop won't stop because it says:

```
while (DataBase.Clientes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == 0) != null);
```

equals to

```
while (I have at least one client with status == 0)
```